# In etc/config.xml This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( default, stores, websites )

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, custom, system-config, default-values

`Magento version : 2.1.11`
I am using a custom module at `custom-module/etc/config.xml` there is below file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <checkDelivery>
            <config>
                <enable>0</enable>
                <postcodes><![CDATA[100000,100001,100002,100003,100004,100005,100006]]></postcodes>
                <success_message><![CDATA[Delivery available]]></success_message>
                <error_message><![CDATA[Item not available at this location, please try another pincode]]></error_message>
            </config>
        </checkDelivery>
    </default>
</config>
```

When I run :`$ php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

```
Element 'enable': This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( default, stores, websites ).                                          
  Line: 6
```

I got above Exception, any idea is there any reserved keywords which this extension is using?

Is there any link from where I can learn about these files and allowed methods.

Update: 
File : /etc/adminhtml/system.xml

```
 <group id="config" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
..............................
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In think you have placed an extra `<config>` tag in your xml or else if you have placed your **group id** config defined in your `system.xml` change it to something else.

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <checkDelivery>
            <mygroup>
                <enable>0</enable>
                <postcodes><![CDATA[100000,100001,100002,100003,100004,100005,100006]]></postcodes>
                <success_message><![CDATA[Delivery available]]></success_message>
                <error_message><![CDATA[Item not available at this location, please try another pincode]]></error_message>
            </mygroup>
        </checkDelivery>
    </default>
</config>
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, is this happen as `config` keyword is reserved ?

Comment: Yes... I think it considers it as the main node for starting the config operation s.

Comment: can you please tell me the use of this etc/config.xml file in M2

Comment: In M2 its usually used to insert the  default value of your system config when you install your module.

Comment: Thank You!,

Is there any link you can share from where i can learn about Magento 2 but at code level or the best way to understand what Magento is.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot specify config tag twice in config.xml

Example in your case replace 2nd  tag with other tag name .
Specify that tag name in system.xml file of your module
Tag name specifies the id of the group tag in system.xml file

Please run upgrade & deploy command and refresh .